# Show that $f(0) + f'(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C\frac{f(w)e^w}{w^2}dw$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Let f be holomorphic on a region containing the closed unit disk $D(0, 1)$ and C be the unit circle traversed anticlockwise. Let n be a positive integer. Show that $$f(0) + f'(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C\frac{f(w)e^w}{w^2}dw$$
and that
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C\frac{f(w)+f(e^{2\pi i/n}w)+...+f(e^{2(n-1)\pi i/n}w)}{w^2}dw=0$$

I am not allowed to use the residue theorem.

I know that $f(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C\frac{f(w)}{w}dw$ and $f'(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C\frac{f(w)}{w^2}dw$ but that only gets me to $f(0) + f'(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C\frac{f(w)(w+1)}{w^2}dw$.

For the second part I tried writing every term within the integral as $\frac{f(e^{2(n-1)\pi i/n}w)}{w^2 {(e^{2(n-1)\pi i/n})}^2}*{(e^{2(n-1)\pi i/n})}^2$ but to no avail as I get to $f'(0) + ... + \frac{f'(0)}{{(e^{2(n-1)\pi i/n})^2}}$.

Any hints/tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "I know that $f(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C\frac{f(w)}{w}dw$ and $f'(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C\frac{f(w)}{w^2}dw$." You know more than this, you know that   $\displaystyle g(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C\frac{g(w)}{w}\mathrm dw$ and $\displaystyle g'(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C\frac{g(w)}{w^2}\mathrm dw$ when $g$ is well behaved enough. Let $g=f\cdot \exp$.

Comment: When $n=1$ and $f(w)=w+1$ for all $w$ in the given disk, the second integral equals $f'(0)\color{grey}{=1}$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the first one, that was really straightforward. About the second one, what you said is obviously true, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: My point is that the second one fails. You want to prove it equals $0$ for any given $n$ and holomorphic $f$, but it fails for the choices of $f$ and $n$ that I mentioned.

Comment: @Drn004 should $n > 1$ for the second part of the problem?

Comment: Thanks Git. Yes Kobe, n is a positive integer.

Comment: @Drn004 I think that's where the misunderstanding comes from. You consider positive integers $n$ to be integers greater than 1, but the positive integers include the integer $1$. So, as Git Gud illustrated, the second part fails when $n = 1$. If you indicated that $n > 1$, then you could prove second equation is true by applying the Cauchy integral formula to the derivatives of $f(\lambda^k w)$, where $\lambda = e^{2\pi i/n}$ and $0 \le k \le n-1$.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It definitely says 'positive integer', but I understood why it fails for $n=1$. Could you please be a little more explicit about how I can get to 0? I did try applying the Cauchy integral formula, but it didn't get me anywhere, it's in the main post what I got. Or did I go wrong somewhere?

Comment: @Drn004 I've put up an answer that is more explicit with the details. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n > 1$, then the second part may be proven as follows. Let $\lambda = e^{2\pi i/n}$. For $0\le k \le n-1$, the Cauchy integral formula for derivatives yields

$$\frac{d}{dw}\bigg|_{w = 0} f(\lambda^k w) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{f(\lambda^k w)}{w^2}\, dw.$$

By the chain rule, $\frac{d}{dw}\bigg|_{w = 0} f(\lambda^k w) = \lambda^k f'(0)$. Thus

$$\lambda^k f'(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{f(\lambda^k w)}{w^2}\, dw\qquad (k = 0,1,\ldots, n-1).$$

Summing the equations from $k = 0$ to $n-1$ results in

$$(1 + \lambda + \cdots + \lambda^{n-1})f'(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{f(w) + f(\lambda w) + \cdots + f(\lambda^{n-1} w)}{w^2}\, dw\tag{*}$$

Since $n > 1$, $\lambda \neq 1$ with $\lambda^n = 1$. So the left-hand side of (*) equals

$$ \frac{1-\lambda^n}{1 - \lambda}f'(0) = 0 f'(0) = 0,$$

and the result follows.